# Laravel query id based array

Tags: php, laravel

I have such results

[image: one]

Bur when I try to get results of different table based on this data (screenshot) ids it says

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

## Code

```
$result = DB::table('zone_regions')
->where('zone_regions.id', '=', $request->input('zone'))
->join('areas', function ($join) use($area) {
    $join->on('zone_regions.id', '=', 'areas.zone_id')
    ->where('areas.id', '=', $area);
})
->join('hthree_regions', function ($join) use($city) {
    $join->on('areas.id', '=', 'hthree_regions.area_id')
    ->where('hthree_regions.id', '=', $city);
})
->join('segments', function ($join) use($segment) {
    $join->on('hthree_regions.id', '=', 'segments.hthree_id')
    ->where('segments.id', '=', $segment);
})
->join('links', function ($join) use($link) {
    $join->on('segments.id', '=', 'links.segment_id')
    ->where('links.id', '=', $link);
})
->join('titik_closurs', function ($join) use($closure) {
    $join->on('links.id', '=', 'titik_closurs.link_id');
})
->groupBy('titik_closurs.id')
->get();
$histories = DB::table('core_histories')->whereIn('titik_id', $result->id)->get(); //get histories of returned results (return error above)
$res = array_merge($result, ['histories' => $histories]);
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$histories = DB::table('core_histories')->whereIn('titik_id', $result->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: `message: "array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given"`

Comment: @mafortis that's a different error to the previous one and it's because you're doing `array_merge` on `Collection` instances instead of their own `merge` e.g. `$result->merge(...)`

Comment: ok i've changed my code to `$histories = DB::table('core_histories')->whereIn('titik_id', $result->pluck('id'))->get();
            $res = $result->merge(['histories' => $histories]);` is there any way that i push each history to their own data instead of all array?

Comment: this is what i get currently https://ibb.co/GWk4c6c is that possible that i have `histories` array inside my data id `52, 53` and the rest just like `histories: []`?